# Regex Exclude Part Of String On Capture C#

Tags: c#, regex, url-rewriting

I am trying to do a url rewrite but can't capture the correct action for two scenarios.  The first is if the action is "`scheduletable`", only capture "`schedule`" in "`action`", otherwise capture the whole thing "`pools`".  My regex keeps including the "`table`" in the "`action`"

```
^/events/(?<action>.*)(?table)?/(?<eventid>\d*).*$
```

**The original URL**

```
/events/scheduletable/39?layout=time&type=all
/events/pools/39
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
^/events/(?<action>.*?)(?:table)?/(?<eventid>\d*).*$
```

And use `$1` and `$2` in the replacement - or your group names even.

[Working on RegExr](http://regexr.com?37a8h)

Answer (score 0):

You had a `?` in the wrong place. `(?table)` doesn't make sense, and your `*` on `action` needs to be non-greedy (`.*?` instead of `.*`). Try this;

```
^/events/(?<action>.*?)(table)?/(?<eventid>\d*).*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following Regex...

```
(?<=events/).*?(?=(table|/))
```

Good Luck!